# Disable validations on close button

Tags: xpages

I have a xpage with a field with empty validation.

On the form I have a close button that navigates away from the xpage to the view xpage.
I want to disable so the validations doesn't run if I click on the close button.

I did set the button property disable validators to true on the button but the 
validators and the error message in the application control is still showing.

Any ideas how to make it work?

Server version:
Domino 8.5.3 UP1

An example to demonstrate the problem. click on button 1 validator shouldn't kickin.
Button 2 validator should show "write something..."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xp:button value="close" id="button1" disableValidators="false">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.test="dsf"}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
<xp:button value="Save" id="button2">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.test="dsf"}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:inputText id="inputText1" required="true" rendered="true"
    disableClientSideValidation="true">

<xp:this.validators>
    <xp:validateRequired message="Write something.."></xp:validateRequired>
</xp:this.validators></xp:inputText>
<xp:message id="message1" for="inputText1"></xp:message>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seams to be a bug

```
<xp:button value="close" id="button1" disableValidators="false">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="true" disableValidators="true">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.test="dsf"}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Check out the first and the second disableValidators="false" the first one comes from when you add it thru the button properties. This one has no effect. second one come from checking the "process data without validation" on the event tab this one works.

Comment: Not sure its really a bug as much as misleading functionality, when you use an eventhandler it processes through that, but if you were to specify an action attribute on the button without an eventhandler than it would use that disableValidators attribute.  Generic JSF doesn't use eventHandler's like xpages does so they use action and actionListener attributes on the buttons.  so in the end the disableValidators on the button is kinda left over from the original  JSF control.